# How to generate a random positive or negative decimal?

Tags: php, random

How can I regenerate random decimal from -0.0010 to 0.0010 with php `rand()` or some other method?

Comment: isn't that only a space of 21 numbers?

Comment: @Fosco that's a space of infinite numbers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Divide `rand()` by the maximum random numer, multiply it by the range and add the starting number:

```
<?php
  // rand()/getrandmax() gives a float number between 0 and 1
  // if you multiply it by 0.002 you'll get a number between 0 and 0.002
  // add the starting number -0.001 and you'll get a number between -0.001 and 0.001

  echo rand()/getrandmax()*0.002-0.001;
?>
```

Comment: Hi Harmen, don't know what reason fomr ur formula i have found a bug there. it generated a -ve 2.plus value.. u have any idea? thanks

Comment: I guess you found a number close to zero, like `-4.7090060121464E-5`. It means `-4.7*10^-5` which is `-0.000047`

Answer (score 3):

.

```
$val = (rand(0,20)-10)/10000;
```

Comment: Now you've really limited to 21 possible values. But perhaps that's what benmsia wants...

Comment: yeah. thx. tho more values generated will be better but if there's no valid solution then i will stick to this temporarily till a new solution is found. thanks nathan.

Answer (score 2):

This uses two rand() calls but I think that the readability makes up for it tenfold.
The first part makes either a -1 or +1. The second part can be anything between 0 and your limit for +/- numbers.

```
$rand = (rand(0,1)*2-1)*rand(0, 100);
echo $rand;
```

Unless you require LOTs of random numbers in a gigantic loop, you probably won't even notice the speed difference. I ran some tests (50.000 iterations) and it came up to around 0.0004 milliseconds to get a random number by my function. The alternatives are around half that time, but again, unless you are inside a really big loop, you are probably better of optimizing somewhere else.

Speed testing code:

```
$start = microtime();
$loopCount = 50000;
for($i=0;$i<$loopCount;$i++)
{
    (0*2-1)*rand(0, 100);
}
$end = microtime();

echo "Timing: ", ((($end-$start)*1000.0)/((float)$loopCount)), " milliseconds.";
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return any **possible** number between `-0.001` and `+0.001`

```
$random = ((rand()*(0.002/getrandmax()))-0.001)
// or without paranthesis:
$random = rand()*0.002/getrandmax()-0.001
```

Comment: You don't need all these brackets.

Comment: Yeah sure, but they don't hurt either

Comment: hi thanks for your input. but it generated a -ve 2.plus value for unknown reason. you have any idea?

Comment: what do you mean by "a -ve 2.plus value"

Answer (score 0):

```
$randselect=rand(0,(array_sum($adarray)*100000000));
$cumilativevalue=0;
foreach ($adarray as $key => $value) {
$cumilativevalue=$cumilativevalue+$value*100000000;
    if($randselect<$cumilativevalue){$selectedad=$key;break;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Random float with one decimal between -1,1

`$random = round((rand(0,1) - floatVal('0.'.rand(0,9).rand(0,9))), 1);`